# Master SAML Processing URL

Tags: saml-2.0, keycloak, keycloak-services

I am trying to create a client that uses SAML, but I am not sure what the  Master SAML Processing URL field should be.

I read the documentation, but its still not clear to me.

Answer (score 2):

SAML uses [assertions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SAML_2.0#SAML_2.0_Assertions) in order to verify resource accesses. The service provider [needs to declare](https://serverfault.com/a/419010/183433) a specific url for this assertion exchange. On the other hand, there's the url which the Service Provider uses to manage the [Single Sign Out](http://xacmlinfo.org/2013/06/28/how-saml2-single-logout-works/) process. The Master SAML Processing URL of Keycloak just lets you specify the same endpoint for both processes (you can still configure them individually using the fine grain configuration).